# Use python to call antiword to convert doc into txt, and find that the return value is garbled

Tags: python, git, shell, powershell

**Problem Description**

I used python to call antiword to convert doc into txt, and found that the Chinese value of the return value is garbled. It is the same situation on powershell. But it is ok to call on git bash.

[image]

env:Windows platform, py3.6

I tried changing locale and tried the -m parameter of antiword, but it didn't work.

**Related code**

```
Pipe = subprocess.Popen(
         ['antiword', filename],
         Stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
         Stderr=subprocess.PIPE )

Stdout, stderr = pipe.communicate()
Return stdoutenter code here
```

Comment: Can you run `antiword` at a command prompt (Powershell or cmd) and get the correct result. Until that is possible, it is unlikely to work from Python. Make it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would help, though I'm using Mac OS, but the logic is more or less the same.

I think you can replace the `['antiword',filename]` to `['antiword','-m','utf-8',filename]`.

What it does is just basically call the mapping file provided in antiword, to map the file to utf-8.txt, then capture by stdout. (For others, you can find some common mapping provided by antiword, e.g. 8859 and cp1251)

Small reminder is to check the name of .txt in your antiword file. One of my friends found that it's UTF-8.txt, but it's utf-8.txt on my laptop.

BTW just want to complain about antiword's encoding, maybe I just not familiar with byte operations cuz I self learn python. The decode for antiword is just tedious. Especially you have a document with mixed languages, header and footer, strange formatting and use the mapping function of antiword. Anyway, good luck.